# count the number of non-NA elements in each row of a data frame before a condition becomes false

Tags: r

Say I have the following data set:

```
mydf <- data.frame(serial = c(1:3),
                   A = c(NA,"2011-01-01","2011-02-01"),
                   B = c("2010-12-01","2011-01-01","2011-02-01"),
                   C = c("2010-12-01","2011-01-01",NA)
                    )
```

There is another vector called limit

```
limit <- c("2011-02-10","2011-03-01","2011-01-12")
```

Think of the limit as a threshold date for each row of mydf. I would like the count the number of non-zero/non-NA occasions for each row of mydf BEFORE the threshold date.
In this case, if I were to store the result in a vector called occasions, it would have the following elements: 2 , 3, 2.

Note: The elements under each column are obviously dates in YYYY-mm-dd format.

Comment: Shouldn't the occasions be 2,3,0?

Comment: It's stated that the date format is YYYY-mm-dd so I would think @Lamia is correct.

Comment: Are you perhaps not reading the ABC as columns and rather reading them as rows?

Comment: Yes, because the question states that the limit is for each row, and the title asks for row counts. Perhaps OP needs to clarify.

Comment: I understood the question to mean that occasions contained row sums.

Comment: The "columns" in a dataframe generally are each of the list elements of which there were 4, but it was fairly clear (I thought) that the `limit`-stopping-values were only to be applied to the last 3 columns. Perhaps if you looked at the print output of `mydf` it would seem less ambiguous?

Answer (score 1):

`colSum`-ing a set of logical vectors created by "<":

```
occasions <- colSums( sapply(mydf[-1], as.Date, format="%Y-%d-%m") < 
                                            as.Date(limit, format="%Y-%d-%m"), 
                     na.rm=TRUE )
occasions
#------
A B C 
2 3 2
```

`as.Date` needed to enforce the logic for logical comparisons, although character comparisons should work if all the values are truly 'YYYY-MM-DD'.